# Error validating entity in PeoplePicker

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker

I am receiving the following exception, if I try to select a user in a PeoplePicker:

```
Error validating entity username: System.ArgumentException: Error during decryption. System error code 0. 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPCredentialManager.DecryptWithApplicationCredentialKey(Byte[] rgbEncryptedPassphrase) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain.get_Password() 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPActiveDirectoryDomain..ctor(SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain peoplePickerDomain) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUserUtility.GetWindowsPrincipalResolvers(SPWebApplication webApp, String userAccountDirectoryPathRestriction, SPPrincipalResolver bySidResolver) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUserUtility.CreatePrincipalResolvers(SPWebApplication webApp, ICollection`1 urlZones, Nullable`1 currentZone, SPPrincipalResolver bySidResolver, String userAccountDirectoryPathRestriction, Boolean alwaysAddWindowsResolver) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolvePrincipalInternal(SPWeb web, SPWebApplication webApp, Nullable`1 urlZone, String input, SPPrincipalType scopes, SPPrincipalSource sources, SPUserCollection usersContainer, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly, Boolean alwaysAddWindowsResolver) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(SPWebApplication webApp, Nullable`1 urlZone, String input, SPPrincipalType scopes, SPPrincipalSource sources, Boolean inputIsEmailOnly) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.ResolveSPEntities(PickerEntity entity, Boolean shouldSetExactMatch) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PeopleEditor.ValidateEntity(PickerEntity entity) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EntityEditor.Validate().
```

This is the stacktrace in the ULS logs. The PP doesnt do anyting actually. Its just showing the name I've entered with a red squiggely line.

If I use the search functionality I am getting the error

> Error during decryption. System error code 0.

I've recreated the AD connection and did a full import, but this didn't help at all, although I now know, that all profiles are reimported and available at least through FIM.

How can I rectify this?